# Stagefright: NuPlayer implementations

Tags: android, stagefright

I am going through the `NuPlayer` implementations in Android `Stagefright`. As per my understanding `NuPlayerFactory` is creating `NuPlayerDriver` in turn it creates `ALooper` and `NuPlayer`. I Couldn't understand `ALooper` and what does it do. I can see all the implementations in `NuPlayer` are invoking `AMessage` calls e.g as below:

```
NuPlyercpp: new AMessage(kWhatSourceNotify, id());
```

I am not sure how does it trigger `NuPlayer::onMessageReceived()`. Could readers please explain?

Comment: The ALooper / AMessage stuff is used to pass messages between threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `NuPlayerDriver` constructor, you see

```
mPlayer = new NuPlayer;
mLooper->registerHandler(mPlayer);
```

This `ALooper::registerHandler()` uses a global `ALooperRoster` to remember the relation between a handler (`mPlayer`) and a looper (`mLooper`).

In NuPlyer.cpp, the general pattern is:

```
sp<AMessage> msg = new AMessage(..., id());
....
msg->post();
```

`AMessage::post()` calls the global `ALooperRoster` to post the message with 0 delay, using the relation that was established in `NuPlayerDriver` constructor.

Comment: @Ganesh: thanks for the enhancements, but I am not sure it was worth the effort.